# Xcode 4.1 sudden strange compile behaviour after crash

Tags: iphone, crash

I've suddenly got a very weird error in Xcode 4.1 that seems to have occurred after Xcode crashed.

I have some Model classes that inherit from a simple base class. Nothing unusual there.

What's happening now is that when I attempt to build for the "device" for one of these model classes that inherit (and only one) it throws a bunch of compile errors saying blah blah undeclared etc. Now if I switch it back to the simulator it builds and runs fine.

This was working perfectly well before the crash. I've done all of the usual clean build, delete derived data, restart XCode etc but still I can't make it work.

If I explicitly add the various bits from the base class into this problematic class it all works fine again.

I'm really perplexed. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You should try a "Product->Clean" and then recompile.

Sometimes Xcode doesn't seem to recognize changes made to files and gives weird errors and warnings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If MrHus' clean doesn't work, Control-Click on your .xcodeproj and select Show Package Contents (Xcode projects are bundles).  Remove everything but the project.pbxproj files; they may be corrupt.

If that doesn't work, try creating a whole new project from scratch.  If that works, then your project.pbxproj was corrupt.